# Install openjdk1.7 u79 package that was downloaded by terminal

Tags: openjdk

Hi guys I download package `jdk1.7.0_79`and I wanted install the package using the terminal.  I got this user guide and I did it step by step.

```
sudo mkdir -p / usr/local/ java
cd/home/ your_user_name /Downloads
sudo cp -r jdk-8u20-linux-/usr/local/java/
cd /usr/local/java
sudo tar xvzf jdk-8u20-linux-x64 tar gz
sudo gedit/etc/profile
JAVA_ HOME= / usr/ local/ java/ jdk1.8.0_20
PATH=$PATH $HOME/bin $JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java" 1
```

I replace every jdk1.8.0_20 with jdk1.7.0_79. but when I paste line 8 I get this error

```
Error alternative Path / usr/ local/java/ jdk1.7.0_79/ bin/ java doesn't exist
```

What is the problem? Can you help me to fix it and tell me what is the correct command? Tanx

Comment: I tried to re-format, but I'm seeing weird things, such as a lot of extra spaces.  Could you try to make this accurate to what you've done?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First read the whole answer, it's possible, that the last part is enough.

---

This line

```
JAVA_ HOME= / usr/ local/ java/ jdk1.8.0_20
```

and this error message

```
Error alternative Path / usr/ local/java/ jdk1.7.0_79/ bin/ java doesn't exist
```

says me, you should use

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79
```

and this PATH definition

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java" 1
```

---

Ok here is the complete block

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
cd ~/Downloads
sudo tar xf jdk1.7.0_79-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/java
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile
```

Add the following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Save the file and start

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java" 1
```

---

Or install the package, the easiest way to install OpenJDK is

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

or Oracle Java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```